# How to delete kubernetes resources across all namespaces?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to know if there is a way to delete specific resources in kubernetes across all namespaces? I want to delete all the services as type of LoadBalancer at once, and have this automated in a pipeline. I already built a xargs kubectl command which will get the name of LoadBalancer services across all namespaces and feed the output to the kubectl delete command. I just need to loop across all namespaces now.

```
kubectl get service -A -o json | jq '.items[] | select (.spec.type=="LoadBalancer")' | jq '.metadata.name' | xargs kubectl delete services --all-namespaces
error: a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces
```

If I remove the `--all-namespaces` flag and run `--dry-run=client` flag instead, then I get a dry-run deletion of all the  services I want getting deleted on all namespaces. Is there a way k8s lets you  delete resources by name across all namespaces?

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
This is the output of running the command using `--dry-run` flag, it gets the name of all the services I want to delete and automatically feeds them to the kubectl delete command

```
kubectl get service -A -o json | jq '.items[] | select (.spec.type=="LoadBalancer")' | jq '.metadata.name' | xargs kubectl delete services --dry-run=client
service "foo-example-service-1" deleted (dry run)
service "bar-example-service-2" deleted (dry run)
service "baz-example-service-3" deleted (dry run)
service "nlb-sample-service" deleted (dry run)
```

The only part missing is that I need to do the deletion across all namespaces to delete all the specified services, I only want to delete services of type LoadBalancer and not other types of services like ClusterIP or NodePort or anything so the specific names must be provided.

Comment: Forgot the  --all flag 

Try `kubectl delete services --all --all-namespaces`

Comment: Hi @ErsinDemirtas I do not want to delete all services, the `kubectl get` part of the command will give me a list of services that are type LoadBalancer and I just want to delete those, other type of services like ClusterIP can't be deleted since that will cause issues to my kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `jsonpath` with the following command:

```
kubectl delete services $(kubectl get services --all-namespaces \
-o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.spec.type=="LoadBalancer")]}{.metadata.name}{" -n "}{.metadata.namespace}{"\n"}{end}')
```

The output of the `kubectl get` command gives a list of `<service_name> -n <namespace_name>` strings that are used by the `kubectl delete` command to delete services in the specified namespaces.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is pretty useful, the problem with it is that it deletes **only the services in the last namespace specified**. However, I think I can create a script to loop over that hopefully. I opened an issue on official kubectl git repo: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1371
According to their reply apparently is not possible to delete resources across all namespaces after filtering certain criteria:
`The intention of the -A/--all-namespaces flag is not intended to be used to delete resources by name.`
Hopefully this functionality is added in the future